# How to put arguments in a function at run time?

Tags: c++, linux, runtime, exec, argument-passing

So I am using execlp in my c++ program. execlp is of the form " int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg0,...,const char *argn)" meaning that it can take arbitrary amount of arguments. I just want to know that is there a way I can put arguments inside this function at run time? Since the arguments are provided by the user, there is no way for me to know the exact number of arguments. Of course I can pick a ridiculously large number from the start but that won't be very efficient.I need a more efficient way that would allow me to put arguments at run time.

Comment: You are missing a Linux or POSIX tag. Your question is probably meaningless on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not required to use `execlp`, `execv` or `execvp` are better functions for your requirement.

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp

> The **execv()**, **execvp()**, and **execvpe()** functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

Comment: @FahadUrRehman, post some example usages and I can responsd to your comment with some concrete suggestions.

Comment: pid_t process; //create process
 process = fork(); //fork it
 if (process == 0) 
 {
  execlp("/usr/bin/ls", "ls", "-la"); //in this case I am passing two arguments. This would result in ls -la being executed in shell
 }

Comment: Create an array (perhaps with `malloc`) of `argc+1` pointers (each of type `char*`), and fill that array.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are using Linux or some other POSIX system.

You obviously need, as [R.Sahu answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30010731/841108), to use functions like [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html), which takes an *array* of arguments to [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall. You could allocate that array in [C dynamic memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) with [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) or friends (`calloc`). If coding in C++, you would use `new`.

For a useless example, here is a chunk of code executing `/bin/echo` on an array of arguments `1`, `2`, .... *nargs*   where `int nargs;` is strictly positive.

Variant in C99

```
assert(nargs>0);
char** myargs = malloc ((nargs+2)*sizeof(char*));
if (!myargs) { perror("malloc myargs"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
myargs[0] = "echo";
for (int ix=0; ix<nargs; ix++)
   { char buf[32];
     snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"%d",ix);
     myargs[ix+1] = strdup(buf);
     if (!myargs[ix+1]) { perror("strdup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   }
myargs[nargs+1] = NULL;
execv("/bin/echo", myargs);
perror("exec echo failed");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

In C++ you would e.g. code `char**myargs = new char*[nargs+2]`;

In general, you need to later `free` (in C++, use `delete`) heap allocated memory. Here it is not really needed, since `execv` does not return. However, in other occasions (e.g. if using `fork` before `execv`, so the parent process is continuing and would later `waitpid`), you need a loop to `free` each individual element (result of `strdup`), then you need to `free` the entire `myargs` array.

Regarding the general question of calling an arbitrary (runtime-known) function of arbitrary signature, this is not possible in plain standard C99, but you could use some libraries (with a few assembler or machine specific code inside them) like [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/)

In  genuine [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you still need the array argument to `execv` to be an array of `char*`. You might consider using (as an intermediate step) some `std::vector<std::string>` but you'll need at least to transform it into a `std::vector<char*>` then pass the data to `execve`. Read about [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (and its `c_str` member function) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (and its `data` member function). You could try something like:

```
 assert (nargs>0);
 std::vector<std::string> vecstr;
 vecstr.resize(nargs+2);
 vecstr[0] = "echo";
 for (int ix=0; ix<nargs; ix++) vecstr[ix+1] = std::to_string(ix+1);
 std::vector<const char*> vecargs;
 vecargs.resize(nargs+2,nullptr); 
 std::transform(vecstr.begin(), vecargs.begin(), 
                  [](const std::string&s) { return s.c_str(); });
 vecargs[nargs+1] = nullptr;
 execv("/bin/echo", vecargs.data());
 throw std::runtime_error(std::string{"exec failure:"}+strerror(errno));
```

Notice that `execv` can fail, in particular when the array of arguments is too big; usually the limit is a few hundred thousands elements, but it can be much smaller.